# Proper use of private and firstprivate in parallelizing a loop (intel fortran)

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran

I am trying to parallelize a loop in Fortran of fairly primitive style (f77+f90).  Form of the loop is

```
do jlink=1,nlinks
j1=links(jlink,1)
j2=links(jlink,2)
<expressions containing array references A(j1),B(j2) and C(jlink)>
end do
```

A, B are arrays 1:nh and C an array 1:nlinks.  A,B,C and links are computed before entry to the loop and don't change during the loop.  C is only accessed once on each trip of the loop . The array links(1:nlinks,2) is only accessed once each trip as shown above. j1 and j2 are just convenience variables re-used once on each trip as shown

Question 1: Is private j1,j2 firstprivate A,B correct

Question 2: Should I declare C or links firstprivate even though only one element is accessed on each trip, which should make them thread safe?

Thanks for advice.  This is my first fore into multi-threading although I have used MPI for explicit parallelization.

Comment: From what you have said A, B, C and links are only read in the loop. Assuming the parallel region you created with $omp parallel contains only this loop if these are read I'm not sure why you want firstprivate - shared is almost certainly what you want

Comment: Thanks @ianbush.  I'm hoping to auto-parallelize with !DIR$ parallel.  I didn't see a "shared" option, maybe it's the default.  A and B are read repeatedly on many loop passes.  The question then is whether cloning them on threads with firstprivate would speed things up by reducing read collisions.  You're undoubtedly right, since I haven't done this before.

Comment: Ahhh, I assumed you were using the standard method, for this, OpenMP. If not I can't help you.

Comment: Hm, I had no idea about this syntax. Maybe you should put `automatic parallelization` in the title/tags.